# read file's data android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to read the script file, I'v putted a filename which is "test.sql". But I got error when I run the code.

**Here is the error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.waiku.work2, PID: 3990
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Pertama": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO `Table1` (name,address,phone,id) VALUES (WK,Taman Pertama,NULL,'4');
                  #################################################################
                  Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                    (near "Pertama": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO `Table1` (name,address,phone,id) VALUES (WK,Taman Pertama,NULL,'4');)
                  #################################################################
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at com.example.waiku.work2.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:100)
```

This is my code where the error line 100 pointed to the `db.execSQL(line);`.

```
 mBtnImport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                try {
                    String filename = "test.sql";
                    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file = new File(sdcard, filename);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;
                    while ((line =  br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                            db.execSQL(line);
                            db.close();
                        }
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upgrade complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                new upgradeDB().execute("", "", "");


            }
        });
```

May I know what is the error?

Comment: You need to quote string values in SQL, e.g. `'Taman Pertama'`.

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean? I don't quite understand...  @Henry

Comment: There are SQL syntax errors in your file `test.sql`.

Comment: I changed `'Taman Pertama'` to `NULL` . Also got this error @Henry

Comment: your SQL query is invalid. There is no problem with reading file.

Comment: This is my query. wrong already? `INSERT INTO `Table1` (name,address,phone,id) VALUES (WK,NULL,NULL,'4');`  
 @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: those are not the values from your question. Which errors do you get with this values?

Answer (score 2):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Pertama": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO `Table1`
>   (name,address,phone,id) VALUES (WK,Taman Pertama,NULL,'4');

Is saying that you have a syntax error. Strings/Text should be enclosed in single quotes.

So need need to use something like

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name,address,phone,id) VALUES ('WK','Taman Pertama',NULL,4);
```

i.e. WK and Taman Pertama need to be enclosed in quotes the number doesn't need to be.